# How to make a version of the `WebSocketDirectives.handleWebSocketMessages` directive that exposes the materialized value?

Tags: scala, akka-http

The directive to handle web-socket messages offered by the akka-http library is, in my opinion, limited.
Most of the stages offered by the akka-stream API are useless if you can't access the materialized value they produce when the graph is materialized. And without access to it, we are limited to a very few trivial stages that are not sufficient for most real world use cases.
The current way to access the materialized value of the flow graph passed to `handleWebSocketMessages` is tricky and intrusive.

So, to support web-sockets nicely, it's imperative to have a directive that extracts the materialized value. The signature would be something like this:

```
def handleWebSocketMessages[Mat](handler: Flow[Message, Message, Mat])(f: Mat => Unit): Route
```

The question is, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation I was able to achieve. Despite it works fine, I am sure it could be improved a lot. So, I won't set this one as the best answer.
One thing that can be improved is the efficiency. The graph I used to extract  the materialized value is interpreted for every new web-socket connection, and I think that that could be avoided.

```
def handleWebSocketMessagesMat[Mat](handler: Flow[Message, Message, Mat])(f: Mat => Unit): Route = {
    def sinkFactory(materializedValue: Mat): Future[Sink[Mat, Future[Done]]] = {
        try {
            f(materializedValue)
            Future.successful(Sink.ignore)

        } catch {
            case NonFatal(e) => Future.failed(e)
        }
    }
    val graph = GraphDSL.create(handler) {
        implicit builder =>
            handlerShape =>
                import GraphDSL.Implicits._

                builder.materializedValue ~> Sink.lazyInit(sinkFactory, null)
                FlowShape[Message, Message](handlerShape.in, handlerShape.out)
    }
    handleWebSocketMessages(Flow.fromGraph(graph))
}
```

Any improvement is welcome.